# Is there a (effective) way to get 5 records to the left and right of a specific record with Access SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Like the title says, I am trying to do a SELECT statement where I am selecting 1 specific record (the one the person searched for) but I also want to get 5 records (the 5 that come before and after the specific one) to the right and left of the specific searched record, while keeping the current/focused record on the searched one.

The records ID's (where they search for) consist out of date values combined with numbers. So for example in this month the first created record looks like this `1602030001` `<-- Year(16), month (02), day (03) and first record (0001)`. So the second one they create this month will be `1602030002` and so on.

So if they search for record 16020050 (50th record in February) I want to show records 16020044 to 16020055.

I already did something like this but it has a downside:
Get the searched record (16020050) and in VBA set a max and min variable (int) to do -5 and + 5 to the searched record number. Then use these variables to do a SELECT like:

`SELECT * FROM SearchRecord WHERE ID > MinVariable (16020044) AND ID < MaxVariable (16020055)`

However, the downside to this is that when the month February for example has only 500 records so 16020500 and then march started (16030001) and the person is searching for the 500th record on February it would also search for records that don't exist (up to 505 while that 5 are already in March --> 16030005).

I don't know a more effective/smarter way to get those 5 extra record to each side and also maintain logic that if you search for the last record in a specific month that the 5 records to the right will start in the next month.

I hope it makes sense;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a table named [MyTable]

```
ID
--------
16020493
16020494
16020495
16020496
16020497
16020498
16020499
16020500
16030001
16030002
16030003
16030004
16030005
16030006
16030007
```

we can get the starting ID of the range centred around ID=16020500 by using the query

```sql
SELECT MIN(ID) AS StartID
FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 6 ID 
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE ID <= 16020500
        ORDER BY ID DESC
    )
```

which returns

```
StartID
--------
16020495
```

and we can simply use that query as a subquery in the WHERE clause of a query to return the 11 rows (5 before + the main one + 5 after):

```sql
SELECT TOP 11 *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    ID >= (
        SELECT MIN(ID) AS StartID
        FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP 6 ID 
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE ID <= 16020500
                ORDER BY ID DESC
            )
    )
ORDER BY ID
```

returning

```
ID
--------
16020495
16020496
16020497
16020498
16020499
16020500
16030001
16030002
16030003
16030004
16030005
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to imagine this is won't be fast though it is a fairly elegant way to think about the problem. This was more common when `top` didn't exist. The initial filter should help restrict the search to a window of ids around the previous two months (assuming there are always at least five records in a month).

```
select *
from SearchRecord sr1
where
        id between [Id:] / 10000 * 10000 - 9999 and [Id:] / 10000 * 10000 + 10005 
    and (select count(*) from SearchRecord sr2 where sr2.id between sr1.id and [Id:]) <= 6
    and (select count(*) from SearchRecord sr3 where sr3.id between [Id:] and sr1.id) <= 6
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to simulate your situation, I created a table variable (you can skip this you have your table) and I used to do the right statement but I dont think this is the best optimized statement. Anyway it worked for my simulated table.

```
DECLARE @SearchRecord TABLE (ID BIGINT)    

DECLARE @i INT=1
WHILE @i<=50
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @SearchRecord SELECT 16020000+@i
    INSERT INTO @SearchRecord SELECT 16030000+@i
    SET @i=@i+1
END
```

--Your Logic

```
DECLARE @SearchedID INT= 16020050
DECLARE @Minid INT
DECLARE @Maxid INT
DECLARE @NearID INT
SET @i=0
SET @NearID=@SearchedID
WHILE @i>=-5
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @SearchRecord WHERE id=@nearID)
    BEGIN
        set @minid=@nearID
        PRINT @minid
        SET @i=@i-1
    END
    SET @nearID=@nearID-1
END
SET @i=0
SET @nearID=@SearchedID
WHILE @i<=5
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @SearchRecord WHERE id=@nearID)
    BEGIN
        set @maxid=@nearID
        PRINT @maxid
        SET @i=@i+1
    END
    SET @nearID=@nearID+1
END

SELECT * FROM @SearchRecord WHERE (ID BETWEEN @minid AND @maxid) OR id=@searchedID  ORDER BY id
```

Comment: I think this problem is specific to Access and your approach looks like Transact SQL.